# Cannot read property 'find' of null with cordova-android 11 in ionic 3

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-android

I have upgraded cordova-android to version 11 to support API Level 31 or above but when I'm creating build its giving error ***Cannot read property 'find' of null***

I have done changes as suggested here [Migrating to Cordova-Android 11](https://ionic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/7891143965975-Migrating-to-Cordova-Android-11)
in **Config.xml**

```
        <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" value="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
```

removed all `<splash>` tags and
uninstalled

```
cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

and

```
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
```

still getting the error , please help

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same problem.
As suggest here, it was caused by some plugins.

In my case, the plugins was :
cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker
phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner

They're not actually maintain anymore, so i had to use those forks, both for the same guy :
https://github.com/geraldapeoples/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner
https://github.com/geraldapeoples/ImagePicker

It's not really a good practice to use forked plugin, but i can't found other working plugin that do the job properly, and don't have the time neither skill to dev a new one by myself.

Migrate to cordova-android 11 is not an easy path, but the doc advised above by Cristian Zumelzu cover most of the problems i met.

Answer (score 2):

im added this to my config.xml
and it works!!

```
<platform name="android">
    ...
    <config-file parent="/resources" target="app/src/main/res/values/themes.xml">
         <style name="Theme.App.SplashScreen" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
              <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">#FFFFFF</item>
              <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/notification_icon.png</item>
              <item name="windowSplashScreenBrandingImage">@drawable/notification_icon.png</item>
              <item name="windowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor">#FFFFFF</item>
              <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">1000</item>
              <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/MyTheme</item>
         </style>
    </config-file>
    ...
</platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have been occurred with one of the plugins. I have faced this problem many a times, hence I always keep a backup of the entire project before any new plugin installation

performing the following tasks should help

cordova platform remove android

and then

cordova platform add android@latest

try with just android instead of @latest in case if you get the same error.

sometimes the json file stores the information and then never deletes it when you revoke the changes.

Answer (score 0):

The are many problems when you are trying to update to cordova-android 11. I recommend you follow in detail step by step in this article for the proper upgrade
https://ionic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/7891143965975-Migrating-to-Cordova-Android-11

Also I had to add "types": [] to the "compilerOptions" in tsconfig.js
After this I solve my problems

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the entire error? There are a few issues when upgrading to cordova-android-11 and also when upgrading to use targetSDK 31 (are you doing both at once? or were you already using targetSDK31?).
This is a pretty standard error. Some things to check:

- Have you upgraded to use java 11 (or higher), java 8 is deprecated.
- Are you using Node 14 or higher? Node 12 is deprecated.
- I believe you should run: `npm i cordova-plugin-splashscreen@6.0.2`, because iOS still needs the plugin (it will not be added for android if you use this version tag).
- I had to patch our cordova plugin qrScanner as it used the term 'compile', which changed to 'implementation'
- I think using a png for your splashScreen icon won't scale to different devices. But I am not sure. (You can create an .XML from an .svg in android studio and use that instead).

If you can share more details, you can get some more precise advice.

Answer (score 0):

This problem usually is related after you update to cordova-android >=11.

Its happening because one of your plugins or in your config.xml you are defining some theme like.

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    </style>
</resources>
```

and now should be

```
        <config-file target="res/values/themes.xml" parent="/resources">
        <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        </style>
    </config-file>
```

In specifically my case was the plugin cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker.

Is still not updated. You need to change this in the plugin.xml of the plugin (that make reference to the resource)

I created a fork with the last changes that allow to run the plugin on cordova-android 12
https://github.com/ZumelzuR/ImagePicker.git

Also there are a PR with this change.

Anyway this could happend with other plugins that you are using